# Crystal reports numeric formula cannot be summarized

Tags: crystal-reports

I currently have a formula (see below) in my report that grabs the most recently updated price for an item within an invoice.  there is an invoice table and a product-price table.  This formula acquires the item's price correctly, but I am unable to summarize the values at any group level.  What exactly makes a field unable to be summarized?

> if {product_price.effective-date} = maximum({product_price.effective-date})
>      and {product_price.effective-date} <= {invoice.invoice-date}then
>              {product_price.price}
>          else
>              0

Thanks

Comment: You cannot summarize a formula that, itself, uses a summary function. `maximum()` is a summary function.

Comment: How are you trying to insert summary in this case?

Comment: You'll want to use a sql-expression field to calculate the `maximum`; you can use it in your aggregate formula.